# Split polygons by area/percentage with QGIS 3.x

Tags: polygon, features, area, splitting, plugins

Is there a function in QGIS 3.6 Noosa that allows me to split polygons with given area or percentage? There is a plugin for QGIS 2. "split polygons" that seems to have exactly what I'm looking for, but it doesn't work with QGIS 3.

So, is there a build-in feature in QGIS 3, that has the same capabilities?

Answer (score 2):

This is a possible approach:

**1.** **Create a Grid** (Vector creation/ Create grid), select the extent of your Layer and a desired spacing/overlay.

**2.** **Create an intersect between your Grid and the original layer**:
    Vector overlay/Intersection.

This will work of course depending on your original shape and on how specific your requirements are.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Plugin in QGIS called **Polygon Divider** that does exactly this: https://github.com/jonnyhuck/RFCL-PolygonDivider